# How to access ClearDB via terminal like Postgres

Tags: mysql, node.js, postgresql, heroku

So I used to use Postgres for Heroku and you could access it with a command like:

```
heroku pg:psql
```

And it would take you to an interface that looked similar to the local MySQL database that you access with:

```
mysql -u admin -p *********
```

Now I want to use ClearDB (my tables are for MySQL), but **how do I actually insert the tables via terminal**, is there a command like `heroku cleardb:something` that will open the interface, or is that not possible?

Should I just convert them back to Postgres?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I clearly just had a stroke.

This is the CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL you get in `heroku config`

```
CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL => mysql://[username]:[password]@[host]/[database name]?reconnect=true
```

And then you just stick it into a command like you do when accessing your local DB

```
mysql --host=[host] --user=[user] --password=[password] --reconnect [database]
```

Or alternatively into your onboard config file

```js
module.exports = {
  'connectionLimit': 100,
  'host': [host],
  'user': [user],
  'password': [password],
  'database': [database],
}
```

Easy peasy, don't know why I didn't catch that.